# Using .hide() on pie series to hide a single slice like the legend event

Tags: highcharts

Having an issue creating an event onClick of a pie slice so that it invokes this.hide() correctly. On line graphs it works correctly when doing:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      events: {
        click: function(event) {
          this.hide();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

That is, when I click on a line series, it hides it and greys it out of the legend correctly.

However, on a pie chart, the same snippet will cause the entire pie to disappear and the legend to become useless.

What is the correct event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to detect clicks on points, for example with the event `plotOptions.series.point.events.click`. When it comes to correctly hiding/showing when you click a pie-slice (point) I think this is the easiest way:

```
click: function() {
    this.setVisible(false);
    return false;
}
```

This sets the point visibility to false, and returns false to prevent the selected state of the point from messing up the display. [Here's a JFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZP49L/1/).